# Ver u ocultar un input de acuerdo a un permiso en react

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un permiso en mi base de datos llamado: per_edit_operaid

const PERMISSION_OPERA_ID = ["per_edit_operaid"];

Aqui hago la validacion del permiso:

```
searchPermission = (permissions) => {
        const userPermissions = JSON.parse(localStorage.permisos);

        const permissionFound = userPermissions.find(item => permissions.includes(item));

        return permissionFound ? true : false;
      }
```

En el input intento hacer un if con la validacion:

```
{
 (()=>{
       const permissionsOper = this.searchPermission(PERMISSION_OPERA_ID);

        if(permissionsOper == true){
  <div className="input-field col s12 m12 l12 xl6" hidden ={this.permissionsOper ? true : false}>
     <i className="material-icons prefix">perm_identity</i>
       <input id="id_profile_sistema" type="text" className="validate"
          value={this.state.item.id_profile_sistema}
          onChange={(event) => this.onChange(event, 'id_profile_sistema')}
     />
   <label htmlFor="id_profile_sistema" className="active">*Opera ID</label>
   <span className="helper-text textError"></span>
   </div>
         }

       })
    }
```

lo que deceo hacer es que cuando el usuario tenga el permiso pueda ver el input de lo contrario no pueda verlo.
Como apunte. no realiza ninguna accion no muestra el input ya sea con o sin el permiso

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Hasta lo que he podido ver con react es que puedes renderizar condicionalmente un componente o una parte de html de dos maneras, como minimo 1 declaras como mismo tienes permissionsOper una llamada campoAMostrar y haces un if donde si se cumple tu condición le asignas el html correspondiente, luego puedes incluirlo en el render como {campoAMostrar} y la segunda opción es con el &&, es decir pones {condicionTrue && <div><input></div>} donde condicionTrue puede ser la llamada a un metodo o la verificación de lo que condiciona el mostrar o no el html que le sigue que seria tu campo de texto

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que puedo destacar de tu código es que estás intentando hacer el render en una función que no retorna nada, por lo que no podrás ver nada. No puedo saber más del contexto porque no muestras más código, pero debes tener en cuenta, hay componentes que aceptan funciones como hijos y otras que no. Pero debería lucir así:

Ejemplo componente que acepta funciones como hijos:

```
<ComponenteConChild>
  {
    () => {
      return <h1>Hola</h1>
    }
  }
</ComponenteConChild>
```

Uno que no acepte funciones como hijos, debes llamar tu a la función (esto pasa sobretodo si el padre no le pasa props al hijo)

```
<div>
  {
    (() => {
      return <h1>Hola</h1>
    })()
  }
</div>
```

En tu caso, de acuerdo al contexto debes identificar con cual de los dos, lo importante es que el contenido de la función debería quedar así:

```
(() => {
  const permissionsOper = this.searchPermission(PERMISSION_OPERA_ID);

  if(!!permissionsOper) {
   return <div className="input-field col s12 m12 l12 xl6" hidden ={this.permissionsOper ? true : false}>
     <i className="material-icons prefix">perm_identity</i>
     <input id="id_profile_sistema" type="text" className="validate"
      value={this.state.item.id_profile_sistema}
      onChange={(event) => this.onChange(event, 'id_profile_sistema')}
     />
    <label htmlFor="id_profile_sistema" className="active">*Opera ID</label>
    <span className="helper-text textError"></span>
    </div>
  }
  return null
})
```

Lo otro que noté es que estás evaluando `if (permissionsOper == false)` lo cual quiere decir que si el usuario no tiene permisos, entonces muestre el input, cuando debería ser si es `true`. Por eso lo resumí así: `if (!!permissionsOper)` lo cual significa una doble negación, es más corto.

> *CONSEJO:* No conozco tu lógica de negocio, pero no recomiendo que guardes los permisos dentro del localStorage, y menos si preguntarás por ellos en tu aplicación, piensa lo fácil que sería escalar permisos, si leo tu código un poco y yo mismo en el localStorage me pongo un permiso de administrador o algo así, sería muy inseguro

Cualquier duda pregunta

Comment: En mi caso si recibe props, ya que el inpu es un campo para edicion en el que trae un numero que recibe por props. YA hice la modificacion como mencionas pero sigue sin realizar la accion. con Respecto a lo que mencionas sobre la seguridad no tengo problema ya que es una intranet y las maquinas tienen bloquedas las acciones como ver la consola. y lo del input false o true solo lo tengo asi por que estaba haciendo unas pruebas lo siento ya lo compuse

Comment: Al parecer no realiza la validacion si hay un permiso o no, solo muestra el input

Comment: Ya intentaste quitar el permiso del localStorage y verificar qué pasa cuando no hay permisos?

Comment: Si, ya lo hice y sigue mostrando el input como si no hubiera validacion

Comment: Entonces actualiza tu pregunta con el código que tienes actualmente, y agrega el valor que estás intentando validar, al igual que la lista de permisos que tiene el usuario con el que haces la prueba, es decir, lo que te retorna el localStorage